# Set attributes of <html> tag using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set two attributes to the `<html>` tag which are:

- dir: rtl
- lang: ar

I've tried:

```
    document.documentElement.outerHTML.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
    document.documentElement.outerHTML.setAttribute("lang", "ar");
```

And:

```
    document.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
    document.setAttribute("lang", "ar");
```

But none of the two worked.

I want to do that because I'm doing a multi-languages (Arabic and English) system for my website using JavaScript.. So I want to set those two attributes incase the language selected was Arabic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove that "outerHTML" stuff from your first example:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang", "ar");
```

Or even shorter:

```
document.documentElement.dir = "rtl";
document.documentElement.lang = "ar";
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `querySelector`?

```
const html = document.querySelector('html')
html.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
html.setAttribute("lang", "ar");
```

Comment: @Nisarg Thanks for finding that. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove `outerHTML` from your first example. `document.documentElement` refers to the `<html>` element:

```js
console.log(document.documentElement) //before setting attributes

document.documentElement.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang", "ar");

console.log(document.documentElement) //after setting attributes
```

```html
<html></html>
```